# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Запуталась. Нужна ли здесь запятая?

В большинстве случаев АФП обеспечивают ресурсное смазывание, то есть смазывание на весь срок службы узла (,) без необходимости повторного нанесения или восстановления покрытия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обороты с союзами *то есть*, *или* (в значении *то есть*) и др. относятся к так называемым пояснительным оборотам и обособляются. Это известное правило см. у Розенталя, как и его пример: Я добрался наконец до большого села с каменной церковью в новом вкусе, то есть с колоннами, и обширным господским домом. В Вашем предложении точно такая конструкция, поэтому запятые Вы вновь поставили верно.

Comment: А ведь действительно. И самое ужасное, что я этот пример из Розенталя очень хорошо помню. А применить опять не смогла...

Comment: Конструкция абсолютно не та, что у Розенталя. У него оборот "то есть" заканчивается "колоннами", а у вас – в конце предложения. У него "в новом вкусе" значит "с колоннами", и больше ничего. Церковь с колоннами, а дом тут ни при чем. А у вас ресурсное смазывание означает "без повторного нанесения". Запятая в середине оборота не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна. Нет причин для постановки.

Comment: Спасибо Вам.